# Set makeprg to VIM function?

Tags: vim

I'm using VIM to work on Visual Studio solutions, and I have written a function that searches the filesystem upwards from the current file and locates the first *.sln file.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
function! BuildSLN()
    " FindSLN is my function that locates the sln "
    let slnfile = FindSLN()
    if slnfile != ""
        execute "!devenv " . slnfile . " /Build Debug"
    endif
endfunction

CompilerSet makeprg=:call BuildSLN()
```

This way, I could use my currently set keybindings for `:make` to build the solution file.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have found a solution, although not technically an answer to my own question :) Since I am loading the compiler settings whenever I enter a C# or VB.net buffer, I am just doing a `let &l:makeprg='"devenv.com "' . FindSLN() . '" /Build Debug"'` in the compiler settings file. I'll leave the question open though to allow others a chance to answer.

Comment: It's better to post your solution as an answer.

Comment: While not strictly answering your question, I find the workflow I like best is to `:cd` (or change dir in `:Ex`) to the root of the project. Then you can simply `:set makeprg=msbuild`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution, although not technically an answer to my own question :)

Since I am loading the compiler settings whenever I enter a C# or VB.net buffer, I am just going to do:

```
let &l:makeprg='"devenv.com "' . FindSLN() . '" /Build Debug"'
```

in the compiler settings file. This gives me the effect that I want, however it technically does not set the makeprg to a function that will be evaluated when `:make` is called, like originally requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a mapping/function/command/whatver that:

- ensure that your makeprg is correctly set
- execute :make
- execute a :copen if there was an error.

Personally, I'd rather have makeprg set when I edit a file from a directory ([that I associate to a project](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/local_vimrc.vim)). And a few mappings to toggle the compilation mode aspects (debug/release, background/or not, target (cross-compilation/or not), multithreaded compilation/or not, etc). Each time one of the aspects is changed, I update makeprg.